# Google Maps API zooming too far out on load

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I can not for the life of me figure out why when I copy and paste the maps API embed code from the google site, that's supposed to be setup to show a location, that it zooms out to show multiple maps of the globe.  If anyone can help me out that'd be great.

I am looking more specifically for a style or something thats small to set the load up zoom?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Please note that the ADDRESS and KEY are indeed valid, I just dont want to post that info on the site.

html:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=ADDRESS&amp;key=KEY"></iframe>
```

Comment: Please provide your code that exhibits the issue, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: [Works for me with a "real" address and my key](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_address.html).  I would suggest you use the [embedded map creation wizard](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start) to make sure it understands your address.

Comment: Is the iframe initially hidden?

Comment: The div its in is initially

Comment: Then that is probably the root of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Use the [embedded map creation wizard](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start).

When I used `q=77+Mass+Ave,+Cambridge+MA` and my key, I got [the same behavior you describe](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_address_bad.html).  When I used the Autocomplete in the embedded map creation wizard, it gave me:

- `q=77%20Mass%20Ave%20-%20MIT%2C%20Cambridge%2C%20MA%2C%20United%20States`
- (`q=77+Mass+Ave+-+MIT%2C+Cambridge%2C+MA%2C%+United+States`)

[which works as expected](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_address.html)

Comment: Thats what I used to make the iframe but it still zooms out too far

Comment: What do you mean by "zooms out too far"? [This](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_address_bad.html)?